# Count the number of messages in an IMAP folder using Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, imap, directory

What is the best way to get the total number of messages in a folder on a gmail account? I can get the number of unseen messages like this request/response:

```
d STATUS "py-lists/pygtk" (UNSEEN)  
* STATUS "py-lists/pygtk" (UNSEEN 10963)
```

But when I want to get the total number of messages:

```
e STATUS "py-lists/pygtk" (MESSAGES)
* STATUS "py-lists/pygtk" (MESSAGES 0)
```

How on earth can the number of unseen messages (10963) be larger than the total number of messages (0)? Am I misunderstanding imap or have I stumbled upon a gmail bug? If so, what can I use as a workaround? Selecting the folder with `f SELECT "py-lists/pygtk"` works, but isn't great as the select operation can take a very long time to complete.

Comment: Do you have that folder selected when you tried it?

Comment: No i did not have it selected

Comment: This looks like a bug in your IMAP server.

Comment: BTW, you can query UNSEEN *and* MESSAGES in a single STATUS query which would be more efficient.

Comment: When I try on gmail, I get: `a STATUS "[Gmail]/All Mail" (MESSAGES UNSEEN)` -> 
`* STATUS "[Gmail]/All Mail" (MESSAGES 662 UNSEEN 161)`